# connecting to an EC2 instance via ssh on a created user

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I can connect to my EC2 instance as root but if I create a user I get a Permission denied(public key) error. Here is the output from `ssh -v`

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to 184.72.242.226 [184.72.242.226] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: identity file /home/amaro/.ssh/identity type -1

debug1: identity file /home/amaro/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048

debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048

debug1: identity file /home/amaro/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2

debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu3

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY

debug1: Host '184.72.242.226' is known and matches the RSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /home/amaro/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering public key: /home/amaro/.ssh/id_rsa

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Offering public key: atkey.pem

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Trying private key: /home/amaro/.ssh/identity

debug1: Trying private key: /home/amaro/.ssh/id_dsa

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Did you add the ssh key to the user, too? Depending on the image only key authentication is enabled.

Comment: hey which key are you referring to? Ive added the /.ssh/authorized_keys as well as the private and public key parts

Answer (score 1):

found the solution had to set permissions to 700 on the .ssh keys thanks for the help